# Why protobuf serialize "oneof" message use if-else

Tags: protocol-buffers

I has a Message define like this:

```
message Command{
  oneof type{
    Point       point       = 1;
    Rotate      rotate      = 2;
    Move        move        = 3;
    ... //about 100 messages
  } 
}
```

Then protoc generate the SerializeWithCachedSizes function:

```
void Command::SerializeWithCachedSizes(
    ::google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream* output) const {
  // @@protoc_insertion_point(serialize_start:coopshare.proto.Command)
  ::google::protobuf::uint32 cached_has_bits = 0;
  (void) cached_has_bits;

  // .coopshare.proto.Point point = 1;
  if (has_point()) {
    ::google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteMessageMaybeToArray(
      1, *type_.point_, output);
  }

  // .coopshare.proto.Rotate rotate = 2;
  if (has_rotate()) {
    ::google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteMessageMaybeToArray(
      2, *type_.rotate_, output);
  }

  // .coopshare.proto.Move move = 3;
  if (has_move()) {
    ::google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::WriteMessageMaybeToArray(
      3, *type_.move_, output);
  }
```

The "oneof" message saves the specific type in _oneof_case_. I think using switch-case is more efficient.

But why protobuf still generate code like this?

Comment: Compilers are smart, so doing either won't probably matter. Compilers are able to transform a long chain of `if/else` blocks into a lookup table. If you try to make a program with a small `switch` block, you will see that the compiler will transform it into several conditional jumps instead. The generation tool probably does it this way because it is way easier to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oneofs are internally handled similar to optional fields. In fact, [descriptor.proto](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto) represents them as a set of optional fields that just have an extra `oneof_index` to indicate that they belong together. This is a reasonable choice, because it allowed oneofs to be used immediately with many libraries before any special support was added.

I assume that the C++ code generator uses the same structure for both optional fields and oneofs.

It is possible that switch-case could generate more efficient code, and in that case it would be useful to propose that as an improvement to the protobuf project. However, like Jorge Bellón pointed out in the comments, it is entirely possible that the compiler will be able to optimize this structure automatically. One would have to test and benchmark to be sure.